# Angular,Typescript: Piping not allowed, what alternative do I use

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, interpolation

I've been struggling to get data piped for my latitude parameter.

On looking for solutions, I have already learned that [ .. ] and {{ .. }} Don't mix.

But what is the solution then?
I've seen a few solutions where they just remove the brackets, this did not work either.

Extra info: I'm trying to use *ngFor to generate markers on a google map.

```
<agm-map [latitude]={{data.point_lat}}[longitude]="lng">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
      <agm-info-window>Text</agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: Did you try `[latitude]="data.point_lat"` (with quotes, of course)?

Comment: Yeah I have, it pops up another error then.

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'point_lat' of undefined"

Comment: Then, as you can see, the error speaks for itself.. `data` is null.. so it's trying to access a property like this `null.datapoint`... to solve your problem use safe navigation operator: `[latitude]="data?.point_lat"`.

Comment: This solves the map not breaking. But how can the data be null? I am able to show it as text.

Comment: What the `data` variable carry? Can you post a sample? Also, the title of this question is a little strange.. what pipe are you talking about?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MU3fRtCT

With this I am able to print out all the coordinates from a .json file.

Ive tried to use the *ngFor to loop the agm-map tag.
It's here that I want to make the latitude equal to the data.point_lng.

The data is text.

I'm sorry if the wording is confusing, it's how we named it in school.

EDIT: I put the code in a pastebin to be easyer to read

Comment: Can you post an example of `data`? You say it is text and not an object?

Comment: I'm sorry, data is not text. I mixed it up with what data.point_lat is, wich is a string. 

https://pastebin.com/mZWQ0gWE

Here is the code for data.